# How to implement list of variables to function from DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, function, dataframe

How can I create funcion in python where in one of parameters I will have possibility to implement list of varaibles of DataFrame ?

For instance I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"TARGET" : [1,0,1],
                   "age" : [22, 54, 67],
                   "power" : [100, 200, 345],
                   "height" : [180, 190, 178]})
```

And for instance I have function:

```
def my_function(data, variables, target_variable):
    .....
```

And in:

- data - I would like to implement my DataFrame (df)
- target_variable - I would like to impelment target variable of my DataFrame ("TARGET")
- variables - list of selected variables from DataFrame for instance ("age" and "power")

  my_function(df, ["age", "power"], "TARGET") - does not work

Comment: Can you explain a little more about you want to in `my_function`? I'm not sure what you mean by 'I would like implement target variable of my Dataframe'. An example would help a lot

Comment: Question is simple, how can I implement list of variables from my DataFrame in one of my function parameter (variables) ?

Comment: What does 'implement a list of variables' mean to you? "a = 1; b = 2" is implementing a list of variables. Do you mean you want your function to act on different columns in your dataframe based on the names you supply as arguments to your function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something to the effect:

```
df.apply(my_function)
```

where

```
def my_function(x):
    x['age'] 
    x['power']  
    x['height']  
    x['TARGET']
    return x
```

once you pass the row in, you do operations on each row by calling your data as noted above. See the apply() and groupby() for passing data to functions